# Accessing nested property of an array

Tags: php

I know this has been answered so many times but I cant seem to work a solution to this particular case. And I also have limited PHP syntax knowledge.

```
<?php $resourceCategory = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'resource_category' );
```

This second line replaces `object(stdClass)#383 (11)` with `array(11)` so it would be easier to access the properties.

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($resourceCategory), true);?>
```

I'm trying to display name from:

```
array(1) {
[7]=>
  object(stdClass)#383 (11) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(7)
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "cat 2"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(5) "cat-2"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(7)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(17) "resource_category"
    ../etc
  }
}
```

with `$resourceCategory->name`. Tried using array integers, array mapping and numerous wordpress functions. Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Just to add i've tried the obvious `$array[7]->name` but this doesnt work for all instances,some categories have 6, 5 etc.

Comment: Can you put the output of `print_r($array)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have object on `[7]` index try

```
echo $array[7]->name;
```

for get all index you need to use `foreach()`

```
foreach($array as $v) {
  echo $v->name;
}
```

Comment: But this int will change depending on what category it is so only works on some. I should have show specific exmaple of using ints, i'll update question.

Comment: so you have more indexs of array?